# Sync database from one device to another

Tags: android, sql, database, synchronization

I created an application which works with database. I have installed that application on my both phone. Now, while using both devices i cant manage data because if transactions that are done in one device, does not show in another device, to do that i backup database from one device and restore in another device but restoring that database will ruin the database and transactions which are already in that device.

So, the thing is, I want to sync data between two of my device such that data from each device should be in another after sync

Comment: Do you have any API to store data on server ?If you have one you can push the data to server and from the other device you fetch the data. In case if you do not have one, have a look at firebase database example. For time being this may serve your purpose. I am using it in my app for small data synch operation

Comment: Are you talking about offline sync?? or online sync? you seem to have problem with Conflicts rather Syncing itself, am I right?

Comment: Problem with firebase database is, database is open to everyone, even to those who are not using the app. I want to sync using wifi or Bluetooth, if possible.

Comment: I want offline sync

Comment: So how far you implemented? can you backup your database to the file? can you transfer files via blt or wifi? can you read and import backed up database from the file?

Comment: Yes. I can backup database file from application and tranfer it via Bluetooth manually and restore the same in another device. I have function for both backup and restore in my application.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the **conflicts**, you can resolve the conflict by writing the more recent records over old records. to do this:

1. Define a field in your records called **lastEdited**. you can choose a `date` or `timestamp` base on what suit you best, Though if you don't plan on displaying this values it's better defining this field as `long` for easier **comparison** later.
2. Each time you **edit** a record **update** the **lastEdited** to the **current** time.
3. After your passed the backed-up Database, read records one by one; Insert the new one but in case of conflict resolve it by comparing the **lastEdited** field between two records.

Hope it helps you ^^
Cheers